# Javascript: Write input parameter in js function

Tags: magento, addition, cart

this here is part of our magento shop system code:

```
<label for="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
<input type="text" name="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />

<p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>qty/3/')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
```

I will add the functionality that I can add more products into the cart with on click. This works when I will add an parameter to this code: `setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>qty/3/')`. My change is `qty/3/`

But this is static. Instead of the 3, I will put here the value of `name="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"`.

I have no idea how this can work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- line breaks are for legibility, you can put on one line if you prefer -->
<button type="button" 
    title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>"
    class="button btn-cart"
    onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>qty/'
             + $F('qty_<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>'))">
    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

I used the [`$F()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-F/) shorthand to get the value of an element.  It's only parameter is the name of an input, and that is the `"qty_<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>"` you knew you had to use somewhere.